# Android Jetpack NavController | Get list of actions for current destination

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm creating a portfolio app that uses Android's new Jetpack Navigation `NavController`. I've created a fragment with a `RecyclerView` that will be populated with views that you can click on to navigate to various app demos (and maybe actual apps I've made if I can figure that out). I'm currently populating the list manually, but I'd like to automate that process.

```kotlin
class PortfolioFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_portfolio, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val navController = view.findNavController()
        val currentDestination = navController.currentDestination

        // How get list of actions?
        val appActions = listOf(
            R.id.action_portfolioFragment_to_testFragment
        )

        portfolio_app_list.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        portfolio_app_list.adapter = PortfolioAdapter(appActions)
    }
}
```

I couldn't find any methods on `NavGraph`, nor `NavDestination` to get the list of actions available for `currentDestination`. I know that my `navigation_main.xml` has them, and I could use `XMLPullParser` or something like that to get them, but I may start using the [Safe Args plugin](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args) which we'll mean that getting the actual class from the XML would be a pain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be considered a bit hacky.

`NavDestination` has a private property called `mActions` which contains the `NavActions` associated with the `NavDestination`.

I solved this by using reflection to get access to it.

```
    val currentDestination = findNavController().currentDestination

    val field = NavDestination::class.java.getDeclaredField("mActions")
    field.isAccessible = true
    val fieldValue = field.get(currentDestination) as SparseArrayCompat<*>

    val appActions = arrayListOf<Any>()

    fieldValue.forEach { key, any ->
        appActions.add(any)
    }
```

The `NavActions` are returned as a `SparseArrayCompat` which is then iterated to obtain the `List`

Comment: That would do it. It is a bit hacky though.

Comment: As always, beware Proguard and add the necessary rules when using reflection like this for release versions. Just a warning for people who run into issues with minification.